# Total Time from MM:SS.SSS format

Tags: google-sheets, time, sum, formatting, duration

I want to get total time of two in google spreadsheet
t1 = 0:57.667
t2 = 01:01.112

Both t1 and t2 format to MM:SS.SSS

When I try to add them with sum(t1;t2) get:
0:00.000 even if it is format to MM:SS.SSS

When I try to add them with t1+t2 get:
„0:57.667“ is text and can`t be changed to number.

Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(SUM(VALUE("00:"&A1:A2)); "[mm]:ss.000"))
```

[image]

Comment: After language changed your solution worked! Thanks!